# Title and menu items of sap.ui.unified.Menu control

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to add title to a `sap.ui.unified.Menu` control and it displays only the title; other menu items after this are not displayed.

How to bind the menu items to this, and how to get same view with other data without new menu element being created?

I want this :

[image: I want this]

I am getting :

[image: I am getting]

My code:

```
sap.ui.define([], function () { 
      var dynamicMenu= new sap.ui.unified.Menu.extend("com.google.copa.common.CustomMenu", {
        metadata: {
            library: "com.google.copa.common",
            properties: {
                title: {
                    type: "string" } } },
        init : function () { },
        renderer:function(oRm,oControl){
            oRm.write("<div");
            oRm.writeControlData(oControl);
           oRm.addClass("myCustTitle");
            oRm.writeClasses();
            oRm.write(">");
            oRm.write("<h2>"+oControl.getTitle()+"</h2>");
            oRm.write("</div>");
            oRm.write(oControl); },
        setTitle:function(val){
            this.setProperty("title",val,true);
            return this; } });
     return dynamicMenu; })
```

This is how I am calling my custom Control:

```
     var menu=new CustomMenu({ title:"MyCustom Title" });

     var oItemTemplate = new sap.ui.unified.MenuItem({
            text: "{description}",press:e=>alert("test") });
     menu.bindAggregation("items", {
                        path: "/plants",
                        template: oItemTemplate });
     thisOfBtn.getView().addDependent(menu);

     menu.setModel(that.getModel());
     // const eDock = sap.ui.core.Popup.Dock;

     // unable to align position of popup 
     // menu.openBy(oButton.getFocusDomRef(),true, "EndTop", "EndBottom","0 -2");
     menu.open(true,oButton.getFocusDomRef(),"BeginTop", "BeginBottom", oButton.getParent().getDomRef());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `oRm.renderControl(oControl)` instead of `oRm.write(oControl)`